# Puppet: Provider npm is not functional on this host

Tags: node.js, puppet

I tried to install bower using puppet. It failed with the error message "Provider npm is not functional on this host".

I ran this on a fresh vm with only puppet / vim installed, and the following module installed.

```
puppet module install willdurand/nodejs
```

Site.pp:

```
include nodejs

package { 'express':
  provider => npm
}
```

This was the error:

```
root@puppet:~# puppet apply site.pp
Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
Notice: Compiled catalog for chef in environment production in 0.29 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/Package[make]/ensure:                                                  ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/File[nodejs-install-d                                                 ir]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/Package[g++]/ensure:                                                  ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/File[/usr/local/node/                                                 node-v0.10.22]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/Wget::Fetch[nodejs-do                                                 wnload-v0.10.22]/Exec[wget-nodejs-download-v0.10.22]/returns: executed successfu                                                 lly
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/Exec[nodejs-unpack-v0                                                 .10.22]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/Exec[nodejs-make-inst                                                 all-v0.10.22]/returns: executed successfully
Error: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/Package[semver]: Provi                                                 der gem is not functional on this host
Error: /Stage[main]//Package[express]: Provider npm is not functional on this ho                                                 st
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/File[nodejs-symlink-b                                                 in-with-version-v0.10.22]: Dependency Package[semver] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Nodejs::Install[nodejs-stable]/File[nodejs-symlink-                                                 bin-with-version-v0.10.22]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/File[/usr/local/bin/node]: Dependency Package[semver                                                 ] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/File[/usr/local/bin/node]: Skipping because of fail                                                 ed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/File[/usr/local/bin/npm]: Dependency Package[semver]                                                  has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/File[/usr/local/bin/npm]: Skipping because of faile                                                 d dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

The only constraint to the `npm` provider to be enabled is if it finds `npm` on the path.  The module creates `/usr/local/bin/npm` which means that `/usr/local/bin` is not present in your PATH variable.

Comment: i'll have a look. I would have expected the module to update the path. thnks!

Comment: It can't, or at least it expects it to already be set.  Managing environment variables are done differently due to user/administrator preference.

Comment: I tried using exec path and still received the same error. Ended up with the hack below.

Comment: Another option would be to creating the npm symlinks into /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
package { 'express':
    provider => 'npm',
    require  => Class['nodejs'], #This fixed it in my case
  }
```